# Enumerating messages in arcpy.GetMessages()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, newline

Messages are present in GetMessages() but it's a formatted string. I want to add some of my own newlines and alter the content on a per-message basis.

How do I access the individual messages in arcpy.GetMessages()?

Comment: Splitting by newline and walking the array members springs to mind.  Skip the last if it's empty.

Comment: Why not use arcpy.GetMessageCount and arcpy.GetMessage and get  them 1 by 1 by index? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/GetMessage/018v0000004t000000/

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comment by @KHibma I put together the code snippet below to demonstrate how to "use arcpy.GetMessageCount and arcpy.GetMessage and get [messages] 1 by 1 by index"

```
import arcpy

try:
    arcpy.CreateFolder_management(r"C:\temp1","test")
except:
    pass

for idx in range(0,arcpy.GetMessageCount()):
    print "Message {}: {}".format(idx,arcpy.GetMessage(idx))
```

As long as the folder C:\temp1 does not exist you should see:

```
>>> 
Message 0: Executing: CreateFolder C:\temp1 test
Message 1: Start Time: Sat Mar 28 11:20:45 2015
Message 2: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
Message 3: ERROR 000732: Folder Location: Dataset C:\temp1 does not exist or is not supported
Message 4: Failed to execute (CreateFolder).
Message 5: Failed at Sat Mar 28 11:20:45 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
>>>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the "Executing" message to be returned when I call arcpy.GetMessages(), but I've got no luck. I get a 0 - 4 loop and no "Executing" line.

Comment: @ddg if you are asking a question then please do that in the area reserved for questions. You can always link to this one for context. Be sure to include the exact code snippet that you are using.